# Let $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ be a group homomorphism. Prove that there exists $n$ such that $G\cong ker(\phi^n)\bigoplus \phi^n(G)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Let $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ be a group homomrphism. Prove that there exists $n$ such that $G\cong ker(\phi^n)\bigoplus \phi^n(G)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm with @Smeef

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079124/show-that-there-is-a-positive-integer-n-such-that-g-cong-ker-phin-tim?rq=1